# Keep duplicates when merging query sets (Django)

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
    queryset = Profile.objects.none()
    for num in temp1:
        queryset |= Profile.objects.filter(subjects_key__contains='-'+str(num)+'-').exclude(user=self.request.user)
```

So currently this code queries every value in the given temp1 array. Essentially I want to build a dynamic or query functionality regardless of the length of this array. It works well, but the only problem is I want to preserve the duplicates as I will need to access the count of them later. Thank you!

TLDR: How can I keep duplicates when merging a query set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**`.union(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union). You can thus simplify this to:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = Profile.objects.none().union(
    *[Profile.objects.filter(
          ~Q(user=self.request.user),
          subjects_key__contains='-'+str(num)+'-'
    ) for num in tmp1],
    all=True
)
```

As the documentation says:

> To allow duplicate values, use the `all=True` argument.

Comment: Thank you for such a rapid response! Although, I did get an error: positional argument follows keyword argument. Working on a fix now.

Comment: @DevinHadley: yes, the `~Q(...)` needs to be placed before the `subject_key__...`.

Comment: Odd, it is now throwing 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax...

Comment: @DavinHadley: what was the value for `num`?

Comment: Apologies, it was my bad! Thanks for the help!